# How to force compiler to emit devirtualized code

Tags: c++, optimization, g++

Consider the following (oversimplified) situation:

`class Base` is a base class with pure virtual function *without virtual destructor* (since it's unnecessary for its intended usage).

`struct A` is a wrapper around function pointer, namely

```
struct A {
    std::string ...;
    ret_t (*f)(base&);
    bool ...;
    /* ... */
};
ret_t f1(base&); // there are corresponding functions
ret_t f2(base&);
ret_t f3(base&);
```

where `ret_t` is some arbitrary type.

And there are functions whose signatures are like `ret_t call(A a)`. For instance:

```
ret_t call(A a){
    derived d;
    return a.f(d);
}
```

where `derived` is derived from `base`, and there are multiple derived class from base.

So far, so good.

However, since `a.f` is called through function pointer, the call to base virtual functions cannot be devirtualized. **That being said**, the derived class is determined at compile time in the function `call`, and thus can be devirutalized eventually theoretically.

That aside, I'm pretty sure, at runtime, only one derived class would be extensively used, and others are unlikely to be called. And I have seen that g++ produce code that do a `cmp` on function pointer if there's only one derived class.

How can I tell g++ to emit code that devirtualize at the final functions `f1, f2, f3`, or to specify that a special virtual function to test against, and thereby optimize more on that?

Comment: Is struct A necessarily a public struct? Scoping classes can make devirtualization easier for the compiler.

Comment: Can the code for struct A be refactored?

Comment: @GermánDiago No, but by scoping classes you mean nested classes?

Comment: If you want your compiler to emit non-virtual calls, you should be able to rewrite your code so that it doesn't use virtual functions or an equivalent run-time dispatch nmechanism (not that you should to, mind you, you just should be able to). Can you? This design fragment doesn't provide enough information.

Comment: @n.m. Pretty much. I used virtual function in base class to hide implementation detail propagating through classes (probably not a good idea..). This way, I can definitely rewrite the code, expose the details and use compile-time dispatch.

Comment: If you hide implementation details from human readers, you also hide them from the compiler. Also, it's a necessary condition but not sufficient. Perhaps the only recourse is to indeed rewrite this to eliminate virtual functionas at the source.

Comment: @n.m., I'd say it would confuse the compiler at worst, since compiler have all information it wanted at compile time. But I'd try to redesign it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the easiest solution is just

```
struct A {
  // ...
  int fi;
  ret_t f(base& b) { switch (this->fi) {
    case 1 : return f1(b);
    case 2 : return f2(b);
    case 3 : return f3(b);
  }
};
```